# which words can replace "pas" on a negation

Tags: négation

I just saw the following sentence in my notes, but I am convinced it is wrong : 'Tu ne te promènes souvent.'

I know some works can be used instead of `pas` like `plus`, but I am betting `souvent` is not one of them.

I found a list of such possible words in an article: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/negative-adverbs/ and it feels complete (using many words I never saw before). Is it?

---

The list, for reference:

ne … pas du tout

ne … pas encore

ne … pas non plus

ne … pas toujours

ne … aucunement

ne … guère

ne … jamais

ne … nullement

ne … nulle part

ne … plus

ne … point

ne … que

Comment: It should be: Tu ne te promènes pas souvent. So, you are right, it was wrong in your notebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the words that can be used as the second part of a negation have a negative meaning on their own. So indeed *souvent* cannot be one.

I can't think of another common negative adverb. There are also negative words that aren't adverbs, in particular pronouns like *rien*, *personne*, *aucun(e)(s)*, and the indefinite adjective *aucun(e)(s)*.

> Je **n'**ai lu **aucun** livre de Hugo.   (I haven't read any book by Hugo.)
> Cela **ne** me gène d'**aucune** manière.   (This does not bother me in any way. — a somewhat old-fashioned way to say it, “*Cela ne me gène pas du tout*” is more idiomatic in modern French.)

Don't bother learning compounds like “*pas encore*”, “*jamais plus*”, etc. The adverb “*encore*” is not part of the negation at all so it doesn't make sense to list “*pas encore*” separately from “*pas*”. And you can use multiple adverbs if needed, e.g. “*ne* … *jamais plus*” = “no longer” (lit. “not ever any more”).

Comment: The page in question is on negative adverbs. *Rien* is a negative pronoun, so it's on another page (along with *personne*): https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/negative-pronouns/

Comment: @lkl Ah, yes, good point, the question was about negative words in general and I hadn't noticed that the list cited by the question was deliberately limited to adverbs.